# Liferay - is it possible to set color scheme for control panel?

Tags: themes, liferay, look-and-feel

The problem is that I have created new theme in liferay together with five color schemes. I have succesfully deployed theme into portal.

Now, I need to set this theme as main theme for Control Panel (control panel->configuration->portal settings->display settings->look and feel). This is not problem, but after selecting my theme there is no option to select any of my **color schemes**.

Is it possible to set color scheme for control panel or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the Control Panel UI there’s no option to do that, unfortunately.

But writing a plugin that does that for you shouldn’t be that hard. After all the Control Panel is just a Group with a theme.

Comment: Uhm, this are a really bad news for me - I am new to liferay portal and I am sure that I will not be abble to write such plugin yet...

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, here is what you can do:

1) write a JavaScript Code (`JQuery` or `Alloyui`), in the `main.js` file of the theme that execute on page load and detect the `Control panel` and change the class of `<body>` to the Color defined in the `main.js`.

2) write a `Hook` to change this JSP : `/html/portlet/portal_settings/display_settings.jsp`.